# how to dynamically group options in selectbox

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-select

Is it possible to dynamically populate a selectbox with options as well as optgroups, using the .options property of the element?

Simplified, this is what I'm doing now (imagine the loop is dynamic, have to do by script):

```js
var demo = document.getElementById("d").children[0];
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
  // this will in this case auto-select and default-select the third option
  demo.options[demo.options.length] = new Option("Value: " + i, i, i == 3, i == 3);
}
```

```html
<div id="d">
  <select></select>
</div>
```

And I'd like to achieve a dom structure like this:

```
<div id="d">
  <select>
    <optgroup label='Something'>
      <option ...
      <option ...
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label='Something else'>
      <option ...
      <option ...
      <option ...
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

I have full control over which and how many options are added to the selectbox, I just like to group them under certain criterias for clarity purposes (for this example just the first 2 and second 3, but not necessarily depending on iterator). But I cannot use any framework/library, it *must* be pure javascript. Also I'm aware of the createElement() method, however I'm using the options property and was just wondering if it could work with that.

If not possible I'd like to know what alternatives I have to dynamically creating optgroups, otherwise I'll just forgo using optgroups altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create the `optgroup` element and append the `options` you create to that element (and then append that `optgroup` element to the `select` element).

Here is a working example:

```js
var demo = document.getElementById("d").children[0];
var optGroup = document.createElement('optgroup')
optGroup.setAttribute('label', 'some value')
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
  // this will in this case auto-select and default-select the third option
  optGroup.appendChild(new Option("Value: " + i, i, i == 3, i == 3))
}
demo.appendChild(optGroup)

var optGroup = document.createElement('optgroup')
optGroup.setAttribute('label', 'some other value')
for (var i = 6; i <= 10; i++)
{
  // this will in this case auto-select and default-select the third option
  optGroup.appendChild(new Option("Value: " + i, i, i == 3, i == 3))
}
demo.appendChild(optGroup)
```

```html
<div id="d">
  <select></select>
</div>
```

The [`Option()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) is a non-standard constructor, however almost every browser has it. The `<optgroup>` element on the other hand doesn't have such constructor, so in order to create it you must use the `document.createElement`.

Comment: So you're saying I cannot do it without createElement(), and cannot use the options property this way?

Comment: Thats correct. I'll update the answer with more information regarding this.

Comment: @JackMcKalling—the Option constructor is from the very early days of DOM scripting, it remains primarily (solely?) for compatibility. *createElement* can be used for all elements.

Comment: For completion puirposes, I just figured out this method doesn't work in IE8, but to fix it, also replace the Option constructor uses by *createElement* and it will work. Unfortunately that way I have to set all properties of the option individually, as opposed to the convenient constructor.

Comment: It's always better to use the standards :)

Comment: @JackMcKalling will appreciate also a vote-up on the answer (now that you have enough reputation for that). Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! And there you go. Someone upvoted before me also.